# What are the per hour or per day governor limits for a managed package app ? are they different from unmanaged apps?

Tags: managed-package, callout, governorlimits

I am developing an app which I plan to publish via App Exchange. The majority of feature of this app will be through HTTP callouts , and these can go in the range of thousands. So what I need to to understand is what are the salesforce limits for managed package apps per day or per hour and are these including the limits for unmanaged app/code.

Answer (score 0):

Managed Packages get their own governor limits for database queries, but most other limits are org-wide. There are limits on the number of concurrent connections to a single server, and a 100 callout per transaction limit, but there are no explicit per hour/day limits on calliuts. As such, you should be perfectly fine.